# Dual Contouring - what is it and how to use it?

Tags: c#, 3d, unity, graphics-programming

I'm having trouble understanding Dual Contouring yet and I need some explanations from someone who has first hand experience.

I searched all I could before writing this question. I've already read:

- https://upvoid.com/devblog/2013/05/terrain-engine-part-1-dual-contouring/
- http://ngildea.blogspot.com.br/2014/11/implementing-dual-contouring.html

And I'm currently working through:

- http://www.frankpetterson.com/publications/dualcontour/dualcontour.pdf
- http://ngildea.blogspot.com.br/2015/03/engine-overview.html
- http://www.oocities.org/tzukkers/isosurf/isosurfaces.html

I'm not used to all the calculus and math and the information doesn't get into my brain. I really need some clarification, or a tutorial, please.

I'm creating a 3D game with destructible map in Unity 5. I implemented a Minecraft-like voxel system. But how does Dual Contouring work (and how do I implement it in C#)? **I don't want to reinvent the wheel**, I want to USE it, but if I can't find a ready-made solution in Unity then I need a grounding in how this algorithm works so I can implement it myself.

**Not solutions:**

[Can someone explain dual contouring?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/83457/can-someone-explain-dual-contouring) is not a duplicate... It's not for me! That question is too straight to the result as the person already mostly understands the proccess. I need help understanding the roles of each function and math components, like the QEF and density.

Also, I looked into Marching Cubes but that won't work for me as I read that it doesn't allow having cubic parts of the mesh in the middle of the smooth ones, and I will use "blocks" in some parts.

Comment: How many questions are in this?

Comment: There are way too many questions in only one question-post. You should edit and focus it. Then later post again. Besides, the "what is it part" is a duplicate post; see: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/83457/can-someone-explain-dual-contouring?lq=1

Comment: Ok, going to edit ASAP. But do I need to create a question for each problem? I kind of needed some explanation around the subject. I'm just newbie on this (Dual Contouring) like that.

Comment: Oh, and about the duplicate: I don't understand the answer; I need some more details.

Comment: [Tried to edit, canceled, and going to try again] ...I don't know how to ask the question. It's not a duplicate for my situation. I don't understand the basics like the user of the other topic does. And I need help to understand it and how to implement it, without "reinventing the wheel" as I said above: I don't want to get too deep into the subject because I'm using Dual Contouring, not creating it...

Comment: I mean, all those questions are just part of a single question. What's the point of existing this website if I can't ask questions? It makes no sense. \o/ And sorry, it's difficult for me to compose a question. I'm not a teacher, not a student, I'm just an amateur programmer. And if I need to know everything so I shouldn't have more questions then there's no real meaning in people using this website...

I don't want to create Dual Contouring again, I want to use it. Unless the code is patented or registered to someone and I can't use it for free. Is the code open for usage or is it registered?

Comment: It's clear that you _are_ an amateur programmer, because one of the first things that one looks for in a moderately experienced problem-solver is the ability to breaks things down and ask one question / solve one problem at a time. That is a fault with your level of experience as a problem solver, not a problem with this site which aims to keep issues focused for good reason (reuse). Don't worry, most of us start that way. Let me edit your question to what I _think_ you need answered most fundamentally. If you don't like it, we can roll back those changes.

Comment: I've +1'ed you, maybe someone else will bring you back up to zero. Remember that such topics are not particularly beginner's topics, computational geometry type stuff can be confusing. Sometimes you need more experience before tackling such things. Also, in future keep all unnecessary cruft out of your text, people don't care and don't want to read a wall of text. Rather err on the side of brevity.

Comment: Ok, I'd really appreciate if you could edit the question; thank you for answering; I felt like I was a piece of c*** by asking my questions and that I did all the wrong and bad things in the world when I shared my newbie problem; so I was going to delete my account later...

I'm learning step by step and I'm doing all the game project alone. 

I understood what you said and that this websites keeps everything focused. But I can't be a "super know-it-all" and make a perfect question. If this website is directed for only professionals and I didn't notice, then tell me and I'll delete my account

Comment: And sorry about the unnecessary parts in the text. I'm brazilian, and like an old teacher I had said, we are an emotional people and we mix emotion with work many times... So we keep it human, something like that. I didn't know it did affect so much my questions and answers.

Comment: Ok, got it! Clean, without explanations, one piece of the subject at a time. Ok, next time I'll try it. By the way, THANKS! You were the only one who helped me.

[It's not easy being depressed and exposing myself in internet to see how people can be cold]

Comment: Glad to help. Have you looked for open source C sharp solutions? - that may be the easiest way to get a working approach of your own!

Comment: I could only find C++ examples. I'm not used to C++ and it's a little more "raw" than C#, but I can understand some parts. I'll try to find C# sources. Thanks. If no one answers and I find the solution I'll totally share what I learnt so nobody needs to pass what I've been through.

Comment: Here's a Unity implementation: -
[tuckbone\DualContouringCSharp](https://github.com/tuckbone/DualContouringCSharp)